# Migration from Java to kotlin - a SAM wrapper challenge?

Tags: kotlin

I have a Java SAM interface and an implementation I want to translate in kotlin:

```
public interface CallbackWrapper {
    <T> Consumer<T> wrap(Consumer<T> consumer);
}

public class MainThreadWrapper implements CallbackWrapper {

    @Override
    public  <T> Consumer<T> wrap(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        return i -> {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(() -> consumer.accept(i));
        };
    }
}
```

Of course our project can deal with the java code but my neurons cannot. ;)

Any help wiil be appreciated.

Patrice

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions (you probably want something along the lines of `return Consumer { /* ... */ }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent Kotlin class would look like this:

```
class MainThreadWrapper : CallbackWrapper {
    override fun <T> wrap(consumer: Consumer<T>): Consumer<T> =
        Consumer { t ->
            val handler = Handler(Looper.mainLooper)
            handler.post { consumer.accept(t) }
        }
}
```

Note that the code uses [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) two times, and they are only available for interfaces declared in Java. The Kotlin alternatives are [function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) or [object expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) for anonymous interface implementations.